# pass in two cookies(duplicate names) into custom HTTP header in AS3 using URLRequest

Tags: actionscript-3

One project I'm working on right now in AIR uses custom headers requires passing two cookies, basically same name, different values.

something like:

```
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie1));
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie2));
```

Apparently AS3 doesn't like that and Charles shows only last cookie is being sent to the server, but not both. I did some search and seems like this is allowed(and the API specifically shows it needs two cookies).

So my question is how can I pass two cookies to the custom header using AS3 URLRequest, or can I even do that with URLRequest?

THANKS A BUNCH!!!

Comment: AFAIK you can pass multiple cookies with the same name, but only one will be accepted, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056306/how-to-handle-multiple-cookies-with-the-same-name
Are you sure the API docs aren't just showing subsequent async calls in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you need to send the cookies in the same header, i.e.

urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie1 + "; " + cookie2));

(Long time since I did AS3.)