# How do cookies work with domains, paths and overriding?

Tags: http, cookies

I have been reading through [How do browser cookie domains work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work) and the RFC at and it answered many of my questions about cookies. Not all of them though (though I'm sure the answer is in the RFC, I haven't been able to properly parse it). I have some more questions, which I will pose in the same format as the above question.

- should a cookie for `www.example.com` be available to `www.example.com/path`?
- should a cookie for `example.com/path` be available for `www.example.com`?
- should `www.example.com` be able to set a cookie for `www.example.com/path`?
- should a cookie for `www.example.com/path` be available to `www.example.com`?
- should `www.example.com/path` be able to set a cookie for `www.example.com`?
- if a cookie is set for `www.example.com` containing `foo=bar`, and after that a cookie is set for `example.com` containing `foo=baz` should `example.com` be sent the former, or the latter or both?
- if a cookie is set for `www.example.com` containing `foo=bar` that expires in a day, then a cookie containing `foo=baz` is set that will expire in 15 minutes, should after the latter cookie expires the former cookie be sent?

EDIT One more:

- if a cookie is set for `www.example.com` containing `foo=bar`, and after that a cookie is set for `example.com` containing `foo=baz` what cookie should `www.example.com` be sent?

Also fixed second case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- should a cookie for `www.example.com` be available to `www.example.com/path`?

Yes

- should a cookie for `example.com/path` be available for `www.example.com`?

No

- should `www.example.com` be able to set a cookie for `www.example.com/path`?

(Yes) Most likely (Cookie Path is not a security feature)

- should a cookie for `www.example.com/path` be available to `www.example.com`?

(No) The cookie will not be sent to `www.example.com`, but `www.example.com` can contain javascript that can fetch the cookie through an iframe. Again, cookie path is not a security feature.

- should `www.example.com/path` be able to set a cookie for `www.example.com`?

Yes

- if a cookie is set for `www.example.com` containing `foo=bar`, and after that a cookie is set for `example.com` containing `foo=baz` should `example.com` be sent the former, or the latter or both?

Latter, because `example.com` does not have access to `www.example.com`'s cookies.

- if a cookie is set for `www.example.com` containing `foo=bar` that expires in a day, then a cookie containing `foo=baz` is set that will expire in 15 minutes, should after the latter cookie expires the former cookie be sent?

No, because the second cookie will overwrite the first.

- if a cookie is set for www.example.com containing foo=bar, and after that a cookie is set for example.com containing foo=baz what cookie should www.example.com be sent?

Unspecified behaviour. Either or both (concatenated) seems to be valid.

[How to handle multiple cookies with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056306/how-to-handle-multiple-cookies-with-the-same-name)

Edit: Added answer to new question, corrected question 2 and changed answer.

Comment: Thank you for the initial clarification. The question comes from a need to implement the client side of cookies manually, so what browsers can do with iFrames is not really relevant to me, just what cookies I should accept, and what cookies I should offer to the server. Should I read 3: yes, 4: no. 7:no, overwrite regardless of expiration

Still open for 6 (not in original question, will edit): which cookie should www.example.com be sent?

Comment: Regarding your last question: This behaviour is unspecified. You can return either or both (concatenated). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056306/how-to-handle-multiple-cookies-with-the-same-name http://www.sitepoint.com/3-things-about-cookies-you-may-not-know/