# document.cookie sets the wrong path

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, path

I usually find an answer to all my questions, but not this time.

I'm trying to store a cookie using javascript on the client browser. Until 2 days ago everything was working perfectly but now my function in some page of my website sets the wrong path.

**The function is the simple:**

`document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/"`

I thought that this is a generic function that make the cookie work in every pages of my website.

If i don't set the specific domain name or the path name  the cookie have to be set for all of my website pages.

**The problem** is that in some pages for some reason that i can't understand the cookie automatically set a wrong path (the actual one),
like 
`/actualpage`

This is a problem because as i get from stack overflow --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/18463119/10557173
if i set a cookie for a specific path, when the url path change the cookie is override and all the function that i made work only if the cookie is not setted start again to work.
This is something that i want to avoid.

**Does someone know how I can force the cookie to always set no path?** `/`

Comment: Do you need to set a cookie? Do you need to send it with every request to the server? If not, use sessionStorage. If yes, use a well used cookie script. Your code does not set /actualpage if you have path=/

Comment: @mplungjan yeah i know that my code do not have to set any path, this is why i can't understand this strange behavior. I don't really need to use cookie but i would like to understand the problem, can i use localStorage to keep the information on the client browser even on different session?

Comment: Yes. localStorage is cross sessions.

Comment: @mplungjan ok thanks, i'll make it work with local storage. But do you have any thoughts about that strange behavior?

Comment: No, I would need to see it in action. The code you posted will not do what you describe - possibly the expiry is set wrong and the path is ignored or the cvalue is not correctly escaped with same result

Comment: ok, thank you again for our quick answere, i will investigate it better.