# 2 cookies with the same name and domain but different paths

Tags: http, cookies, path

I have a cookie named `cookie1` on domain `domain1.com` with path `/`
and several pages afterwards I get another cookie with the same name and the same domain but on a different path `/path`.
When a browser requests pages underneath `/path`, which of the cookies will it send? Which one of them will count as the good one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle multiple cookies with the same name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056306/how-to-handle-multiple-cookies-with-the-same-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer is Nate's answer from [How to handle multiple cookies with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056306/how-to-handle-multiple-cookies-with-the-same-name/24214538#24214538)

TLDR summary: 
Nothing is guaranteed as it is not fully defined. We may get only the cookie under /path or both of them. And the order we will get them will be also unknown.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running into the same issue myself. From my research, it looks like **if you have two cookies with the same name, but different paths, the cookie that will be used is the one that matches the path of the current page**.

For example, if you have two cookies:

```
'name=myCookie; path=/'
'name=myCookie; path=/Main/'
```

and you are on the page `/Main/index.html`, the second cookie will be used.

Also, the more specific the path, the higher the precedence. This [SitePoint article](http://www.sitepoint.com/3-things-about-cookies-you-may-not-know/) states:

> If multiple cookies of the same name match a given request URI, one is
>   chosen by the browser. The more specific the path, the higher the
>   precedence.

So if you are on the page `/Main/something/whatevzdude/index.html`, you will also get the second cookie.

Comment: Check out the comment to my answer (that links to a duplicated question), it has a good answer. Basically you are right but it can be browser dependent so don't count on it.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm hoping to go another route. Here's my [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610090/updating-cookie-expiration-only-if-path-matches-page), in case it interests you.